# Error while building SQL server database project in VS2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a database application already created which I'm trying to build in VS2013 but it always throwing an error as:

```
Error 101 03073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin>sgen.exe" "C:\D\GoogleGeoCoder\GoogleGeoCoder\bin\Debug\GoogleGeoCoder.dll"" exited with code 3. 
File => "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets"
```

What is `Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets` and for what purpose it is used?

What is `sgen.exe`?

How to resolve above build error?

Answer (score 0):

Following steps working in my case:

Steps:

- Right click on project and go to properties.
- Select `Build Events`
- Change `sgen.exe` path to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\sgen.exe`
- And also check the path provided for `dll` is correct.